# Scale image in HTML

Tags: html, css

I have div in html which should hold 10 equal divs inside of it with some pictures and text. My div height and width is in percentages. I have to put some images in those divs but the problem is I don't know how to calculate which height x width of images I need.

Images should be bingo balls and I have made balls with size `128x128`.

This is my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z5DKj/2/), div with white border should hold image and image `should scale` with div.

Div with green border should have 10 divs with blue border. Every div with blue border should have div with white border (image div) and div with red color (some text that should be right of the image).

Everything that I tried was unsuccessful.

Comment: Could you post a photoshop image of what your goal is? It's hard to figure it out just reading.

Comment: Sure, here you go: http://tinypic.com/r/103d995/5

Comment: And what scales? What do you want it to look like if the page is bigger??

Comment: Div "bingo" already scales to screen size because its size is in percentages. I want to add 10 divs like in the picture and i want those divs to scale also but i want image to scale and keep aspect ration.

Comment: Use `max-width: 100%; height: auto;` on the image.

Comment: If I use 'max-width: 100%; height: auto;' picture is 128px. I need picture height to be 'height of div' and width to be proportional to stay in same aspect ration as original picture.

Comment: attribtes width and height in img only take numbers and their unit are pixels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took your image here: http://tinypic.com/r/103d995/5 and made an example that is stretchy and keeps its proportion.

**[Live demo (click).](http://jsbin.com/uzObiyO/3/edit)**

**Sample markup:**

```
  <ul>
    <li><img src="//placehold.it/50x50"><span>Some Text</span></li>
    <li><img src="//placehold.it/50x50"><span>Some Text</span></li>
    <li><img src="//placehold.it/50x50"><span>Some Text</span></li>
    <li><img src="//placehold.it/50x50"><span>Some Text</span></li>
    <li><img src="//placehold.it/50x50"><span>Some Text</span></li>
    <li><img src="//placehold.it/50x50"><span>Some Text</span></li>
    <li><img src="//placehold.it/50x50"><span>Some Text</span></li>
    <li><img src="//placehold.it/50x50"><span>Some Text</span></li>
    <li><img src="//placehold.it/50x50"><span>Some Text</span></li>
    <li><img src="//placehold.it/50x50"><span>Some Text</span></li>
  </ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
ul {
  list-style: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 15%;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

li {
  float: left;
  clear: both;
  border: 10px solid black;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: lightblue;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 100px;
}

li img {
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: auto;
  width: 25%;
}

li span {
  width: 75%;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

If you want to also scale the text, check out the new css3 `vw` unit or for older browsers, use javascript. There's a script called **[bigText](http://www.zachleat.com/web/bigtext-makes-text-big/)** that you might be interested in.